# Axios POST return nework Errro when using ipv4 as url in React Native

Tags: react-native, axios

I am trying to call a post api in react native using axios:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `https://xxxxyz/registration`,
    data: {
      app_code: appCode,
      type: 1,
    },
  })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.data) {
        return response.data;
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('register api error', err);
    });
```

This is working, but when I replace the url to ivp4 address, I got an network ERROR.I have tested the address on postman, it worked well.

```
 axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `https://12.34.555.666/registration`,
    data: {
      app_code: appCode,
      type: 1,
    },
  })
```

can anyone help ? Thanksss